Determine if a value is earlier or later than time
I have the following data:
times <- c("20:00","17:00")
df <- data.frame(times)
df$times <- as.POSIXct(df$times, format = '%H:%M')

Now, I would like to create an extra rule that detects whether it is earlier than 5 PM. Therefore I have tried:
df$off_hours <- ifelse(df$times < "17:00", 1, 0)

But this gives me:
"Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) :
character string is not in a standard unambiguous format"
Any thoughts on how I cant improve this?

You need to convert "17:00" to time then you can make a comparison:
cutoff_time <- as.POSIXct("17:00", format = '%H:%M')

df$off_hours <- +(df$times < cutoff_time)

Here is the full example https://www.mycompiler.io/view/7YpyU3n13Ut

df$off_hours <- +(df$times < cutoff_time) is an order of magnitude faster, no need for ifelse.
